# Load matrix from .dat file Matlab (except remove first 8 rows)

Tags: matlab, matrix, load

To simplify my problem, I am trying to load a file named `data.dat`.

I however do not know how to import a only a specific number of rows. For example:

```
Blue Red Green
1     2    4
1     3    4
0.1   2.2  3
.
.
.
```

How do I go about only importing rows from `0.1` and below. I do not want the first 2 rows nor the headers.

I know this is a fairly simple problem but I keep running into the following error:

> Error using textscan. Invalid file identifier. Use fopen to generate a valid file identifier.

```
fid = fopen('data.dat', 'r');
mat = textscan(fid, '%f', 'HeaderLines', 1);
fclose(fid);
```

I thought that this works by removing the first row but I am clearly mistaken.

Comment: That means that `fopen` could not open the file, hence your file identifier (`fid`) is negative and `textscan` recognises this as the file being corrupt in some way.

Comment: In the docs on [`fopen`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fopen.html) is a small bit about displaying the relevant error if the file doesn't open. Please run that and return the error message, if it's different from the one you already got that is. "If `fopen` cannot open the file, then `fileID` is `-1`.", I think your `fid` is indeed `-1`.

Comment: This is almost certainly because you're in the wrong directory, or you don't have permissions to open the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *dlmread* command like single line of the code below (I'm assuming that your file located at the current working directory, otherwise use the correct path):

> mat = dlmread('data.dat','',4,0);

Note: You don't need to open/close the file.